# How should I store my static text data inside an IOS app

Tags: ios

I have about 100-150kb of data(string) and I want to display it in my app.

I was reading about Core Data, but because I won't change my data I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.
What method should I choose for storing this data ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with your strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to store data in an iOS-App. This sounds like plist-files are the best way for your case. In plists (property-lists) you can store data organized as a dictionary for example.

EDIT:

But if you want to use your strings for localization in your app I recommend using StringFiles. For localization purposes you can access them more easily.